# TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating an online shop for learning node.js. When I delete a product from products.json file, respective products in the cart.json are also deleted. I get the following error in the picture when I try to delete a product. This is the code!

In products.ejs

```
<form action="/admin/delete-product" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<%=product.id%>">
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

After linking controller, in the controller function I have
In admin.js controller,

```
// import product model
const Product = require('../models/product');
// delete a product
exports.postDeleteProduct = (req, res) => {
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  Product.deleteById(prodId, () => {
    res.redirect('/admin/products');
  });
}
```

Then in the product.js model, I have

```
// import cart model
const Cart = require('./cart');

// get all the products from the file

const getProductsFromFile = cb => {
  fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
    if (err) {
      cb([]);
    } else {
      cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));
    }
  });
};

// delete by id

static deleteById(id, callback) {
    getProductsFromFile(products => {
      const product = products.find(prod => prod.id == id);
      const updatedProducts = products.filter(prod => prod.id !== id);
      fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(updatedProducts), err => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('Product: ',product);

          //also delete in the cart
          Cart.deleteProduct(id, product.price, callback);
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Upon executing the code, I get the following error. Notice, how there are two console outputs for 'Product'. One for the actual Product and second `undefined` for some reason!

[image]

Comment: Add check that `product` and `updateProducts` are actually not null before calling `fs.writeFile()`?

Comment: `products.find(prod => prod.id == id)` is returning undefined. Replace it with this `products.find(console.log)` to log each product (will also returned nothing). Also, log the product ID before `getProductsFromFile`. From there you can ensure the ID you expect is passed, and check that it exists in the logs of each product.

Comment: Mr. Stefan Becker I added `if(product) {
            console.log('products:',product);
            Cart.deleteProduct(id, product.price, callback);
          }` the undefined output is gone. But application is still crashing!

Comment: Mr. Callam I did what you told. It returns the correct id! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static deleteById(id, callback) {
  console.log('deleteById', { id });
  getProductsFromFile(products => {
    let deletedProduct = null;
    let updatedProducts = [];

    for(const product of products) {
      if(product.id === id) {
        deletedProduct = product
      } else {
        updatedProducts.push(product);
      }
    }

    if (!deletedProduct) {
      console.log('deleteById: Product not found', { id });
      callback();
    } else {
      fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(updatedProducts), err => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('deleteById: Product', deletedProduct);
          Cart.deleteProduct(id, deletedProduct.price, callback);
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I added the callback below `console.log('deleteById: Product not found', { id });
callback();` to redirect and that did it! Thanks :)